# Excel 2010 will not calculate

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Excel 2010 has bombed (stopped working properly) previously, and now again. It will not calculate a simple formula =SUM(C5:D5). I checked all of the answers shown and none of those fixes work. Is this just a really bad version of Excel?

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] your question to indicate exactly what Excel *does* do? A screenshot would probably be a nice addition for clarity. If you don't have the rep to post it directly, just post it anywhere and include a link in your question, and (assuming that it is legitimate) someone will edit it into the question itself.

Comment: I can't find any way to add the screenshot, so here's my best DIY:

Comment: Sorry, hit that Return by mistake. Formula: =SUM(C5:D5) in E5          Column   C5 - 17.95       D5 - 7.47      E5 -  17.95

Comment: So your problem is that when you try to sum a range, you get only one of the values in that range, not the sum of the range?

Comment: Yes, only one of the numbers is in the sum.  I have tried summing both horizontally and vertically.  Also, I have my Calculations set to Automatic. I have another spreadsheet that I used regularly, and it is working fine.  I have also tried copying the formula to notepad, then back into Excel, as suggested by someone.  At this point, I'll try creating a completely new spreadsheet, but I still think there is something wrong with Excel 2010; it has glitches.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your question does not say what Excel is doing...

but if I have to guess, you probably have calculations set to manual (rather than automatic).  You can change this Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculations > Automatic

Comment: Answers are intended to be definitive solutions rather than guesses (the site is a knowledgebase), and it's kind of hard to answer when the question isn't clear .  With a little more rep, you will be able to leave helpful suggestions as a comment.  If a guess turns out to be the solution, it can be reposted as an answer.